# Python NLTK Lazy

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I am attempting to analyze a text in Python using NLTK but when I run the program I get an error that says TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not callable. I'm not exactly sure why I am getting that error.

```
import re
import csv
import nltk



class project:



    def __init__(self):
        self.ReadDoc()


    def ReadDoc(self):

        PPV = nltk.corpus.words('/Users/documents/project/docs/txt/file.txt')
        PPV = ' '.join(PPV)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was due to not defining the corpus variable.

It should look like this:

```
import re
import csv
import nltk



class project:



    def __init__(self):
        self.ReadDoc()


    def ReadDoc(self):

        corpus_root = os.getcwd() + "/docs/txt/"
        file_ids = ".*.txt"
        corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, file_ids)

        PPV = nltk.corpus.words('file.txt')
        PPV = ' '.join(PPV)
```